# Calling custom free C routine from C++ destructor?

Tags: c++, c, memory, free, destructor

I have a C++ program called `myArchive` that calls routines from a static C library.

My code for `myArchive` has a class called `Archive` that contains a private variable called `md`, which of type `Metadata *`, defined in my C library.

Here's the `myArchive.hpp` header:

```
#ifndef MYARCHIVE_H
#define MYARCHIVE_H

#include "myLibraryHeaders.h"
...
namespace Archive {
    class Archive {
        public:
            Archive();
            virtual ~Archive();

            Metadata * getMd() { return md; }
            Metadata ** getMdRef() { return &md; }
            void setMd(Metadata *_md) { md = _md; }
        private:
            Metadata *md;
    };

    Archive::Archive() {
        md = NULL;
    }

    Archive::~Archive() {
        if (md != NULL) 
           freeMetadata(&md);
    }
}

#endif
```

The `freeMetadata()` function is just releasing items in a linked list:

```
void freeMetadata(Metadata **md) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Metadata *iter;
    Metadata *prev = NULL;

    if (! *md)
        return;

    for (iter = *md; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
        /* ... */
        if (prev != NULL)
            free(prev);
        prev = iter;
    } 

    if (prev != NULL) {
        free(prev);
        prev = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration in one of the headers referenced in `myLibraryHeaders.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef METADATAHELPERS_H
#define METADATAHELPERS_H

typedef struct metadata {
    /* ... */
    struct metadata *next;
} Metadata;

/* ... */
void freeMetadata(Metadata **md);
/* ... */

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I have some other variables, but this is the stuff relevant to my question, which is:

When I try to compile this, I get an out-of-scope error:

```
...
g++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DUSE_ZLIB -DUSE_BZLIB -O3 -Wformat -Wall -Wswitch-enum -static -c myArchive.cpp -o myArchive.o
myArchive.hpp: In destructor "virtual myArchive::Archive::~Archive()":
myArchive.hpp:87: error: "freeMetadata" was not declared in this scope                                                                                                                                                  
make: *** [myArchive] Error 1
```

But I am including a header file (in `myLibraryHeaders.h`) that declares `freeMetadata()`. Further, the compiler isn't complaining about the `Metadata` type, which itself is also defined in one of the headers in `myLibraryHeaders.h`.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you're only calling the function when `md` is null. What does the header look like?

Comment: Fixed that typo. I'm re-writing my code to fit into the SO question field, and I missed that. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the header that prototypes the freeMetadata function? That would at least rule out typos and the like

Comment: Your `myArchive.hpp` misses a `;` after the class definition. This shouldn't compile (but with a different error than the one you describe).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this typo. If I comment the `freeMetadata(&md)` line, this binary works as expected. I just can't free `md`, which is the specific problem.

Comment: I wonder if somehow freeMetadata is getting stuffed into someone elses namespace showhow? If you comment the call out and compile/link, can you do "nm -a -C | grep freeMetada" (or whatever the windows equivalent is if you are not on a *nix) and see how it is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation that makes sense is that you're somehow getting `METADATAHELPERS_H` defined prior to the include of myLibraryHelpers.h, probably due to some prior include somewhere -- some kind of circular include dependency.  You can try using `g++ -E` to extract the post-preproceesed text and try to see if you can untangle the problem from that (search for where freeMetaData appears in that to get some idea of the order that you're ending up with), but in general solving these problems can be tricky

Comment: if that were the case, i'd think it would complain about any line that uses a Metadata variable. I think it's actually fairly easy to test by simply changing the METADATAHELPERS_H to something else